Sorting surnames alphabetically w/bubblesort
I have a question which needs me to sort out surnames. I'm using bubblesort, but I'm having trouble splitting the first name and the surnames. I have this going on before using my bubble sort method.
public class Surnames
{
  public static void main(String args[])
{ 
      String names[] = {"Dippy Duck", "Annie Apple" etc}
       char[] charnames = names.toCharArray();
       bubblesort(charnames);
       String sortedString = new String(charnames);
           System.out.println(sortedString);

public static void bubblesort(char[] charnames)
{
     int limit = charnames.length;
     for(int i =0; i < limit -1; i++)
      {
         for(int j =0; j < limit -i - 1; j++)
          {
            if(charnames[j] > charnames[ j+1])
              {
                char temp = charnames[j];
                charnames[j] = charnames[j+1]
                   charnames[j+1] = temp;
                 }
            }
    
        }
 }

I'm trying to get it to print out like Annie Apple and then sort them out alphabetically but I don't know.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To better understand how this site is intended to be used, these resources, and resources they link to may help: The Tour, Help Center, How to Write a Good Question, and Minimal Reproducible Example.

(1) Unless the question is about compiler error message(s), the code sample in your question should compile cleanly.  (2) If the question is about compiler errors, the question should have an exact copy of the error message, and you should indicate which code / line triggered the error.  Cutting your example array of names short and replacing it with etc causes a compiler error. Also, in this case, it reduces the quality of the example.

This line char[] charnames = names.toCharArray(); causes a compiler error.  I suspect you wanted to use String#toCharArray (), which works on one String. But, the method is not defined for an Object of String [].

There are several sub-steps in this in which I could imagine a person needing help. Which of them do you need help with? If it's "all of them, I just need general debugging help", that's too broad/off-topic for this site. Otherwise, please specify exactly the sub-steps you need help with, along with what you tried, what you expected and why you expected it, and what you saw instead. (Chances are good that going through that exercise will help you answer your questions on your own!)

Old Dog Programmer's example of trying to use a non-existent String[].toCharArray() is a great example. The question there is "how do I split each element of an array of strings"? So, take that question by itself and see if you can answer it.

I cleaned the code.

Type x[] is the old C/C++ compatible style, better keep the type together: Type[] x.
Your array bounds using limit seem a bit wrong. I took the liberty to use an other name (n).
Debug, or trace the solution.

The second j loop is feasible, but you'll find the following simpler:
import java.lang.System.Logger;
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
...

private static final Logger LOGGER = System.getLogger(Surnames.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Dippy Duck", "Annie Apple"};
    for (String name: names) {
        char[] nameChars = name.toCharArray();
        bubblesort(nameChars);
        String sortedName = new String(nameChars);
        System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", name, sortedName);
    }
}

with
public static void bubblesort(char[] chars) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "bubblesort: {0}", chars);
    int n = chars.length;
    boolean swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) { // i and i+1 valid indices.
            if (chars[i] > chars[i + 1]) {
                char temp = chars[i];
                chars[i] = chars[i + 1];
                chars[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "swapped: [{0}] {1}", i, chars);
            }
        }
        --n;
    } while (swapped);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "result: {0}", chars);
}

Using a Logger would have helped to run a check.
